# getting a type mismatch/cast error I don't understand when using array Concat

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I'm trying to use the array Concat method to combine a literal, hard-coded array of a type called SearchDef.Column with an array returned by a static function on my class. The static function also returns SearchDef.Column[]. This is the basis for an end user query tool which combines a number of built-in fields with end-user defined fields. So, I want to combine a literal array with one returned by a function, and I want the presentation to be seamless between the built-in and user-defined fields. I've left out a lot of the surrounding code because it's a lot, and I don't think it helps with the question.

I'm getting the familiar "are you missing a cast?" error when I use Concat to combine the results of my static function with the literal array.

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AdamOneilSoftware.SearchDef.Column>' to 'AdamOneilSoftware.SearchDef.Column[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

This doesn't make sense to me because the main Columns property (at the top) is of type SearchDef.Column[]. The static function SearchDef.CustomFieldsFromQuery also returns SearchDef.Column[], so I don't understand why the compiler is calling it IEnumerable. Indeed I tried casting the result of CustomFieldsFromQuery directly, but was left with the same error. I also tried putting .ToArray() on the end -- no change.

I hope I've given enough source code .... try not to get hung up on the string literals/SQL fragments. In an of themselves, they aren't the problem. Rather it's some kind of array type mismatch that I don't follow.

```
        Columns = new Column[] {
            new Column("[p].[Number]", "Number"), 
            new Column("[p].[Name] AS [PatientName]", "Name"),
            ... ommisions for clarity ...               
            new Column("[mc].[Number] AS [Microchip]", "Microchip")
        }.Concat(SearchDef.CustomFieldsFromQuery( // FAILS HERE
            "SELECT [Name] AS [Header], 'dbo.Patient' + [ccft].[StorageColumn] + ... omitted for clarity
            "WHERE [fd].[ClinicID]=@0 AND [fd].[ShowInSearchResults]=1 AND [fd].[IsActive]=1"));
```

Here's the code for the CustomFieldsFromQuery method:

```
    public static Column[] CustomFieldsFromQuery(string query)
    {
        // query must return 3 columns: Header, Expression, ID and have a formatting placeholder {0} where the ID will be inserted into expression
        Hs4Db db = new Hs4Db();
        DataTable tbl = db.SelectTable(query, SqlDb.Params(db.CurrentClinicID), CommandType.Text);
        return tbl.AsEnumerable().Select(dataRow => new Column(dataRow)).ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share the code of the `CustomFieldsFromQuery` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're misdiagnosing the issue.

You are attempting to assign an IEnumerable to it. Your code is effectively:

```
Columns = (IEnumerable<Column>)someValue;
```

You should change this to :

```
Columns = ((IEnumerable<Column>)someValue).ToArray();
```

Putting this into your code gives:

```
Columns = new Column[] {
        new Column("[p].[Number]", "Number"), 
        new Column("[p].[Name] AS [PatientName]", "Name"),
        ... ommisions for clarity ...               
        new Column("[mc].[Number] AS [Microchip]", "Microchip")
    }.Concat(SearchDef.CustomFieldsFromQuery( // FAILS HERE
        "SELECT [Name] AS [Header], 'dbo.Patient' + [ccft].[StorageColumn] + ... omitted for clarity
        "WHERE [fd].[ClinicID]=@0 AND [fd].[ShowInSearchResults]=1 AND [fd].    [IsActive]=1"))
.ToArray() // Note the ToArray on the *outside*...;
```

Answer (score 3):

`Concat` returns an `IEnumerable<AdamOneilSoftware.SearchDef.Column>` and the `Columns` property you assign it to is probably a `AdamOneilSoftware.SearchDef.Column[]`.

Append a `.ToArray()` after your `Concat` call and it will work fine.

Comment: thank you -- took me a bit see that you meant put it at the very end